# Defining exception classes

Tags: c++, exception

I'm wondering if it's generally a good practice to define your own exception classes for a given program. For example, I have a program that mainly does reading from/writing to files, and modifying iptables rules. I've written the program its own basic logger class as well. To handle unexpected values or errors such as opening files, I typically use `std::runtime_error`. I am wondering if defining my own exception classes is generally a good idea. Example:

```
void Protocol::set_port(const unsigned long &port) {
    if ( (port > 0) && (port < 65535) ) {
        port_ = port;
    }
    else {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid port number");
    }
}
```

I don't like using a whole bunch of try and catch blocks, since I find it to be a bad and ugly practice (although I may be wrong).

Comment: Yes, defining your own classes is ok. But please inherit from `std::exception` or it's subclass. You can throw anything, but people expect some child of `std::exception`.

Comment: Defining your own exceptions allows for a lot of flexibility. Also, there's nothing wrong with try catch; they exist for a reason. Like anything, they can be abused.

Comment: @AndyG I usually throw `std::runtime_error` exceptions so that the program exits with e.what(), without catching exceptions using try blocks. Would try and catch blocks be needed/preferred in the above example then?

Comment: Defining your own exception classes and the appearance of too many try/catch blocks are two completely different topics.

Comment: @user9518704: Whether you want to catch an exception or not is usually specific to what expectations you and your team want to set on the function. There's no right or wrong answer.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Fair enough. I'm just trying to clear some misconceptions that I may have about exceptions and exception handling.

Comment: @user9518704: Well, if you have so many try/catch blocks, then chances you are using exceptions like return codes. But exceptions are meant to transparently traverse many layers of code, and the one which handles an exception will usually be far away from the one which throws it. And if you have so many `catch` handlers in one place, then how exactly will their behaviour differ? Are you just going to log a message and quit or will you do something more elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering if it's generally a good practice to define your own exception classes for a given program.

Yes, in general the exception's type should be descriptive of the source or cause, so you can handle that particular exception through pattern-matching rather than code.

> I typically use std::runtime_error. I am wondering if defining my own exception classes is generally a good idea.

Yes, in general you should follow these rules:

1. Obviously, only use exceptions to report exceptional failures (i.e. a precondition not being met, or a resource being unavailable for reasons beyond your program's incorrect operation).
2. If the failure is a logical error (the caller is trying to do something illegal within your program's domain) then derive your exception from `std::logic_error`.
3. If the failure is a result of an invalid argument, then it would make sense to derived from `std::invalid_argument`.
4. If the failure is a runtime error (e.g. file missing) then derived from `std::runtime_error`.

   It can also be useful to nest exceptions, since you can then pass both a summary and a cause of the exception for later diagnosis, example:

```
struct port_out_of_range : std::invalid_argument
{
    port_out_of_range(std::string const& context, unsigned long given)
    : std::invalid_argument(context + ": port given: " + std::to_string(given))
    {
    }
};

void Protocol::set_port(const unsigned long &port) 
{
    if ( port < 65535 ) {
        port_ = port;
    }
    else {
        throw port_out_of_range("Protocol::set_port", port);
    }
}
```

... later ...

```
try {
    // ... some things ...
    foo.set_port(x);
    // ... more things ...
}
catch(port_out_of_range& e)
{
    // maybe some remedial action possible here
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{
    // but not here
    log(e);
    throw;
}
```